# Using dot notation on a subclass of NSManagedObject caused an UnrecoginzedSelectorException

Tags: ios

```
@interface Account : NSManagedObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *encryptedPassword;
```

and I did use @dynamic for that property

```
@dynamic encryptedPassword;
```

In I did set the class of the model to Account

But it raises that exception when I try to access encryptedPassword using dot notation like:

```
account.encryptedPassword
```

While using KVC is completely fine:

```
[account primitiveValueForKey:@"encryptedPassword"]
```

Could you please tell me how to fix this?

---

For the following code

```
@try {
    NSLog(@"Primitive Value: %@", [account primitiveValueForKey:@"encryptedPassword"]);
    NSLog(@"Value For Key: %@", [account valueForKey:@"encryptedPassword"]);
    NSLog(@"Dot Notation: %@", account.encryptedPassword);
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Found: %@", exception.reason);
}
```

I got

Primitive Value: <0f43f1e0 c4c4e0ab 97c524f4 b8483430>

Found: [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Account is not key value coding-compliant for the key "encryptedPassword".

Comment: What is your data model and does `valueForKey:` work.

Comment: It's defined as Binary Data, non-optional, and nothing else different from normal attribute. Oh and valueForKey: doesn't work though.

Comment: And you created the class manually rather than having Xcode do it. What is the difference with the auto-generated version?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) There was a typo in my original .h file. And I think it doesn't matter to use strong instead of retain, does it?

Comment: Strong and retain are the same really.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is created properly it should work. There is some mismatch between the model and the class. This would most usually be in the naming of the attribute (property). Regenerate the class from the model using Xcode and compare to find the difference.

Comment: Thanks you so much. Actually after regenerated the .h file I found a typo in the original one.